# generate or forward a touch event to a view?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view with tap_gestureRecognizer.
This might sound silly, but when a tap is recognized, I'd like to forward that touch to the view that's associated with the recognizer, and to the subview of the view in the end.

I should explain why I have the recognizer in the first place.
It's there to grab touch which wouldn't have been captured because of a scroll view.
[WWDC 2012 scroll view session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) briefly mentions it.

(scroll view blocks touch to a view behind it, but if the view behind has a gesture recognizer, it can recognize the touch)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, UIGestureRecognizers has a property, cancelsTouchesInView that does exactly this. The default is YES which prevents the touches from being delivered to the view. By setting it to NO, both the gesture recognizer and the view will receive all touches.

```
gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

From Apple's documentation:

> If a gesture recognizer doesn’t recognize its gesture or if the value of this property is NO, the view receives all touches in the multi-touch sequence.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll try it soon, I suspected "multi-touch sequence" implies tap_gesture is not relevant here because it's a single touch sequence.

Comment: I had the code in place already, the view which has the recognizer doesn't receive touch.(touchesBegan doesn't get called)